# Is there a way to turn off email notifications with find my iPhone?

Tags: find-my-iphone

Is there a way to turn off email notifications in find my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it's not possible to disable security notifications from iCloud services.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do that.